# Trying to configure email in Identity server

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I have configured the email configuration in identity server repository/conf/output-event-adapters.xml with the below settings.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< outputEventAdaptersConfig>
   < parameter key="mail.smtp.from">name@companyname.com< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.companyname.com< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.port">25< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.auth">false< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.user">name< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.password" / >
< /outputEventAdaptersConfig>
```

but while sending email i am getting the below error

> [2019-05-22 06:24:37,892] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.OutputAdapterRuntime}
>   -  Connection unavailable for Output Adopter 'EmailPublish org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.ConnectionUnavailableException:
>   The adapter EmailPublisher failed to connect to the mail server due to
>   null smtpfrom value

tried the same configuration in axis.xml also. we are using 
WSO2 Identity Server 5.5.0

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
< outputEventAdaptersConfig>
   < parameter key="mail.smtp.from">name@companyname.com< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.host">smtp.companyname.com< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.port">25< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.starttls.enable">false< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.auth">false< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.user">name< /parameter>
   <parameter key="mail.smtp.password" / >
< /outputEventAdaptersConfig>
```

> [2019-05-22 06:24:37,892] ERROR
>   {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.internal.OutputAdapterRuntime}
>   -  Connection unavailable for Output Adopter 'EmailPublish org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.core.exception.ConnectionUnavailableException:
>   The adapter EmailPublisher failed to connect to the mail server due to
>   null smtpfrom value

Comment: maybe it's because you put a space in a tag: `< parameter ...`. should be like this: `<parameter ...`

Comment: No I added the space for formatting in the blog. The XML is valid without spaces

Comment: the error occurred when property `mail.smtp.from` not defined. please edit your question and provide correct xml that you have tried.

Comment: Hi, The first line in the configuration is mail.smtp.from only

Comment: again: the config you've provided is incorrect. please edit your question and fix it. otherwise nothing to answer here.